# Access blob storage through azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure blob storage, which contains some CSV files.
My task:

```
1. Create a logic app for the blob storage.
2. Retrieve the data from the blob storage.
3. Convert the retrieve file to JSON.
3. Upload that data to an online portal through API.
```

I've tried retrieving the data by "Get blob content" action, but not sure where to see the result. I have just created the logic app, but I'm stuck on what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This is the output of get blob content. Is there any way to convert this output to JSON]For your question about

> I've tried retrieving the data by "Get blob content" action, but not sure where to see the result.

When you run the logic app, you can see the content of your csv file in the `OUTPUTS`, shown as below:

[image]

If you want to use an api to upload the data, you just need to do the operation like below screenshot(but it also depends the type of your api's request body) :

[image]

Since you mentioned your azure storage blob contains some csv files, so maybe you need to loop the files. You can use "[List blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#list-blobs)" action and "[For each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop)" action to loop them and then get blob content.

[image]

Hope it helps, if you have any further problem, please let me know.

Comment: .Thanks i was able to retrieve data through 'get blob content' but its output is not in JSON form. How to convert the output to JSON then send it over API.

Comment: Hi @user10050258, sorry I'm a little confused. You mentioned the files in your storage is csv type, doesn't right ? Could you please share a sample of your data ?

Comment: yes, the files are uploaded are csv file . But after i retrieve it from "Get Blob Content" , the output is in octate/binary form. I want the output in JSON form.

Comment: @user10050258 Ok I see. If you want to convert csv to json, you can refer to this [page](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/microsoft-flow-advanced-tutorial-creating-a-csv-converter-from-scratch/).

Comment: The page can't be open

Comment: @user10050258 Do you use your company vpn ? I test my company vpn and my private network, both of them can open this page.